# dash input suggestions using 'list' doesn't work

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to get the browser to autocomplete searches based on values from a list.
here is the relavant part from the dbc.Input docs:

```
list (string; optional): Identifies a list of pre-defined options to suggest to the user. The value must be the id of a <datalist> element in the same document. The browser displays only options that are valid values for this input element. This attribute is ignored when the type attribute's value is hidden, checkbox, radio, file, or a button type.
```

here is my code:
[image]

but still, when I start typing there are just no suggestions:
[image]

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are providing string instead of variable, this doesn't seem right?

Comment: where am I providing string instead of variable?

Comment: you have list='pokemon_names' which either is just a string, or should be some kind of css selector, like '#pokemon_names' - hard to tell when the code that you are showing is only a small part, and you provide is as a image instead of code. 
Is there any error in console in chrome debugging tools?

Comment: the docs states the value of 'list' should be the idea of the datalist element - this is why it is a string. isn't that right?